# motion прекращает работу с непонятной диагностикой

Tags: linux, rtsp, motion

Имеется IP-камера и motion, который настроен по [этому ману](http://95.31.214.51/x/tags/linux/rtsp) (пишет с RTSP по движению). Несколько месяцев всё работало как часы. Но в последнее время появились стабильные сбои после часа-двух работы:

```
/* тут пока ещё нормально */
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 78
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] mlp_actions: End of event 78
/* а тут глюк выскакивает */
[1:ml1] [ERR] [NET] netcam_proc_jpeg: Camera width/height mismatch with JPEG image -  expected 640x360, JPEG 320x180 retval 18
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] mlp_capture: Restarting Motion thread to reinitialize all image buffers
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_loop: Thread exiting
[1:nc2] [NTC] [NET] netcam_handler_loop: netcam camera handler: finish set, exiting
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Motion thread 1 restart
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 is from /home/xxx/bin/motion.ffmpeg
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 Camera Name: (null) Service: http:
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_start_thread: Stream port 0
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] vid_start: Opening Netcam
[1:ml1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_start: Network Camera starting for camera ((null))
[1:ml1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_read_first_header: Found Conn: close header ('Connection: close')
[1:ml1] [NTC] [NET] netcam_setup_html: connected, going on to read image.
[1:ml1] [CRT] [NET] netcam_start: Width/height(320x180) must be multiples of 8
/* и всё, камера потеряна */
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] vid_start: Netcam failed to open
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] motion_init: Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1:ml1] [ERR] [ALL] motion_init: Motion only supports width and height modulo 8
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_loop: Thread exiting
```

Причём сама камера продолжает работать, MJPEG и RTSP-потоки с неё видно, можно зайти в админку через веб-интерфейс, и т.д.

Есть идеи, что это может быть и как лечить **motion**?

Comment: думаю, ошибка здесь "netcam_start: Width/height(320x180) must be multiples of 8" - а почему камера решила работать в таком нестандартном разрешении - а кто его знает.

Comment: @KoVadim, почему камера так решила другой вопрос. Но главный - почему motion её после этого вообще теряет и не может реконнектиться, хотя она жива и продолжает гнать все потоки в таком разрешении, как нужно. То есть если параллельно с глюком смотреть тот же поток VLC, например, там никаких сбоев и трансляция не останавливается.

Comment: для работы модуля motion нужно, что бы разрешение было кратно 8. Так он сделан. Но для трансляции это не есть преградой. Сделайте разрешение правильным и motion после перезапуска сам подключится

Comment: @KoVadim, сделать разрешение правильным я не могу, потому что не понимаю, что в мозгах у камеры происходит :) Может быть односекундно.  Но, повторю: никакого изменения разрешения с точки зрения VLC и других клиентов в этот момент не происходит, они как ловят исходное, так и продолжают ловить.

Comment: ну тогда поменять камеру. Или настроить ручное перекодирование.